# In Veloeclipse How to change color of JavaScript content?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, velocity, eclipse-juno

Am using veloeclipse, but javascript content colors are paled Green,want to change little dark,Is there anyway to achieve this.?

I used the plugin by this URL  http://veloeclipse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/update/

Please give you guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open "preferences", scroll down to "Veloeclipse", open it, select "Editor", select "script code", click "color" and change the color to something more visible ;-)